# Do we use the present simple tense in the following context?

Tags: future-time, present-simple

> Captain, if they attack us , what do we do?

I am a bit confused over whether or not  "what do we do?"  Is correct in the previous context. Do we 
use the future simple tense instead?

Comment: I would say "what should we do". But I can't find any reason to say "do we do" is wrong.

Comment: There is no future tense in English. You can use many constructions to refer to future time, including the present simple and "future will."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not uncommon in informal English speech to substitute present indicative for future indicative, especially when you are talking about plans or consequences as opposed to predictions.

"At noon, we eat."

"If anyone touches this button, everybody in the room *dies!*"

*but*

"By the end of 2018, the Dow will hit 25,000."

(In the first two cases, the future would be correct as well, if a bit stiff; in the last case, the present would make no sense.)

**Edit:**

The original sentence "Captain, if they attack us, what do we do?" is perfectly idiomatic and correct.

A more formal phrasing is, "what *should* we do".  The speaker is asking for orders or instructions, and that takes "should" or "ought".

The simple future, "what *will* we do" would only be correct if the speaker were asking the Captain for his prediction of the reaction of speaker and his friends will be to an attack -- "what *do you think* we will do" -- and I don't think that's the case.

Comment: I understand you, but what about the sentence I provided? Is it correct or formally acceptable or not?

Comment: @AhmedAyman -- response in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Albeit bit personal but here is another view on the difference:

> What do we do

is about reacting to a particular situation. There are maybe protocols that change based on who is attacking. Meaning here **THEY** are significant for the context. Maybe you can pull punches or go all out or do other things depending on who **They** are.

> What should we do

in general, like what do we do in case of an attack, from anyone.

Comment: That's a good point, in fact, but I would like to know if the future simple fits in the sentence or not ?